# colocar dois botões um ao lado do outro

Tags: html

estou estudando html e estou desenvolvendo um site para a minha loja, entretanto cheguei em um impasse que não sei como resolver e gostaria de vossa ajuda. Quero colocar dois links de contato um ao lado do outro mas não sei como, e atualmente o código está assim:

```css
main {
  text-align: center;
}

main a {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Contato - Leoni Modas</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="contact.css">
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <ul>
      <a href="https://wa.me/5555999089824?text=Ol%C3%A1!%20Vim%20pelo%20site%20da%20Leoni%20Modas%20e%20preciso%20de%20mais%20informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es!" target="_blank">
        <img src="./img/wppp.png"></img>
        <P>WhatsApp</P>
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/leoni_modas/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
        <img src="./img/instaa.png"></img>
        <P>Instagram</P>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

O que posso fazer para colocar os botões um ao lado do outro?

Answer (score -3):

Tem muitas formas de atingir o resultado que queres, mas de forma simples precisas de mudar um dos atributos predefinidos da tua lista (ul)

main ul {
display: flex;
}